# Google Cloud SQL connection limit is not the same as in the documentation

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I created a postgres instance yesterday, mirroring one we already had set-up. However it seems the default 'max_connections' is set to 25 rather than 100: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps

While connecting to the database I get the following result:

```
      name       | setting 
-----------------+---------
 max_connections | 25
```

How can I set the number of max_connections to 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh-oh, docs are out of date. We gotta fix that, thanks for reporting!

Cloud SQL's PostgreSQL connections scale with the instance size. You are probably using "micro" instance. Upgrading to "small" will give you 50 concurrent connections, first non-shared-core machine (1 CPU, 3.7G RAM) will give you 100, larger instance will give you more than a 100.

Comment: Why does MySQL enjoy significantly more connection limits, i.e. 4000 as opposed to Postgres?

Comment: Seeing how "well" tiny MySQL instances perform with 4000 connections is actually what motivated us to limit connections in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I can understand that. Unfortunately in the wild things like this are the stuff that becomes the deal-breaker on whether on not to migrate to GCP. People are just so used to virtually unlimited connections on RDS, never mind the part about instability.